# Need advice to structure my mongoDB database

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I just started to use mongoDB. I'm trying to use it in a side project but i have some issues to structure my documents.
It's a very specific subject but I'm translating it to a real word example.
Here's the topic, I have data for shops in my country. There is one shop per regions. There is a set of items (a lot of items) that can be found in every shops. For each items I have an ID and some data (price, quantity, ...). The thing is that the price for the items change each day and i want to keep an historic of the data for 30 days.

The user will have to choose their region, then choose several item to compare them.

I already tried some things like this model :

```
region_id: Number,
items: [{
    item_id: Number,
    item_data:[itemDataSchema]
}]
```

but I think will have issues because of the size of the document after saving 30days of data

And a friend of mine suggested me this one but isn't really familiar with mongoDB either :

```
item_id: Number,
region_id: Number,
item_data:[itemDataSchema]
```

Writing this I think it might be complicating things and that the answer might be really simple. I have trouble visualising the structure I need. That why I'm asking you some help.
Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is limit in size of documents in mongodb so structure you're thinking have chances to reach the limit

What I think is you should make 2 collections 1 will contain documents for regions ( information about region only with region_id ) and second collection will contain documents per item and will have region_id, other data related to that product and array item_price which will have object having values date and price to store 30 days price history

This is how item documents will be like

```
{ item_id
  region_id, 
  Item_data,
  Item_price : [ { date : Date, price : number }]
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I think i'll go this way.